# Navigating from App.xaml.cs when receiving push notification

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Hi i want my app to navigate to a page when i receive a push toast notification. My code is as follows:-

```
ParsePush.ToastNotificationReceived += OnPushNotification;
```

This is to handle the event of push

```
private async void OnPushNotification(object sender, Windows.Networking.PushNotifications.PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var AdFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
            var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
            if (localSettings.Values.ContainsKey("Suspended"))
            {
                String value = localSettings.Values["Suspended"].ToString();
                if (value != null)
                {
                    if (value == "false")
                    {
                        AdFrame.Navigate(typeof(Ad));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I get a Null Reference Error at `var AdFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;`

I have added this code in App.xaml.cs .I just want to navigate to the Ad Page from current page , whatever page maybe active. I am pretty new to windows , any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to display a toast notification instead:

```
XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(
    ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText02);

XmlNodeList stringElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
stringElements.Item(0).AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Hello world!"));

IXmlNode toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");

XmlAttribute launchAttribute = toastXml.CreateAttribute("launch");
launchAttribute.Value = "pass data here"; // TODO: pass data here
toastNode.Attributes.SetNamedItem(launchAttribute);

ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

When user clicks on the toast notification, you can handle the App launch event and then read the data.

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    // ...

    MainPage page = rootFrame.Content as MainPage;
    page.ParseData(e.Arguments);
}
```